# No output with wexpect code in either IDLE or PyCharm

Tags: python

I am trying to open a command prompt window and interact with it to automate a process. Before the automation however, I am having difficulty in getting wexpect to work properly.

When I run the code I with just the spawn member, I am not seeing a command prompt window open. There is no error message being displayed in IDLE and when I run it in PyCharm I receive an error score of 0.

When I add the sendline member, I am seeing a confusing output (shown below) in IDLE and no output along with an error score of 0 in PyCharm.

Am I missing something fundamental here?

Here is my code:

```
import wexpect

cmdcommand = wexpect.spawn("cmd.exe")
cmdcommand.sendline("cd C:\cygwin64")
```

The output with the sendline member in IDLE:

```
[PyINPUT_RECORD(EventType=1) (KEY_EVENT), PyINPUT_RECORD(EventType=1) (KEY_EVENT), PyINPUT_RECORD(EventType=1) (KEY_EVENT), PyINPUT_RECORD(EventType=1) (KEY_EVENT), PyINPUT_RECORD(EventType=1) (KEY_EVENT), PyINPUT_RECORD(EventType=1) (KEY_EVENT), PyINPUT_RECORD(EventType=1) (KEY_EVENT), PyINPUT_RECORD(EventType=1) (KEY_EVENT), PyINPUT_RECORD(EventType=1) (KEY_EVENT), PyINPUT_RECORD(EventType=1) (KEY_EVENT), PyINPUT_RECORD(EventType=1) (KEY_EVENT), PyINPUT_RECORD(EventType=1) (KEY_EVENT), PyINPUT_RECORD(EventType=1) (KEY_EVENT), PyINPUT_RECORD(EventType=1) (KEY_EVENT)]
{'Size': PyCOORDType(X=80,Y=16000), 'CursorPosition': PyCOORDType(X=32,Y=3), 'Attributes': 7, 'Window': PySMALL_RECTType(Left=0,Top=0,Right=79,Bottom=24), 'MaximumWindowSize': PyCOORDType(X=80,Y=41)}
[PyINPUT_RECORD(EventType=1) (KEY_EVENT)]
{'Size': PyCOORDType(X=80,Y=16000), 'CursorPosition': PyCOORDType(X=46,Y=3), 'Attributes': 7, 'Window': PySMALL_RECTType(Left=0,Top=0,Right=79,Bottom=24), 'MaximumWindowSize': PyCOORDType(X=80,Y=41)}
```

Expected output with the command prompt window displayed:

```
C:\Users\Pushya Krishna>cd C:\cygwin64
```

Comment: Unfortunately, [wexpect has an issue](https://github.com/raczben/wexpect/issues/1) with IDEs